# Python encoding graph to json

Tags: python, json, graph, encode

I am trying to create the following JSON text by iterating through a graph which contains this data:

```
{
"random" : [
    {
        "attr1" : "X",
        "attr2" : "Y"
    },
    {
        "attr1" : "Z",
        "attr2" : "V"
    }
    ]
}
```

I tried this:

```
output = ""
for node in graph:
    output += json.JSONEncoder().encode({"random": [{"attr1": graph[node].attr1, "attr2":graph[node].attr2}]})
```

But this causes the "random" to be repeated before each entry, like this:

```
{"random": [{"attr1": "X", "attr2": "Y"}]}{"random": [{"attr1": "Z", "attr2": "V"}]}
```

How do I prevent the "random:" for being repeated? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what graph is equal to, because as it stands your code doesn't make any sense. The `for node in graph:` will loop once and yield node = "random". What's the point of even looping? Why are you hard coding the attribute names `attr1` and `attr2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you are concatenating the strings for separate nodes instead of just dumping the whole structure at once?

```
>>> import json
>>> graph = {
... "random" : [
...     {
...         "attr1" : "X",
...         "attr2" : "Y"
...     },
...     {
...         "attr1" : "Z",
...         "attr2" : "V"
...     }
...     ]
... }
>>> json.dumps(graph)
'{"random": [{"attr2": "Y", "attr1": "X"}, {"attr2": "V", "attr1": "Z"}]}'
```

First, it is simpler and faster. Second, the concatenation of yours does not even produce a valid JSON.

Comment: thanks, sorry I'm very new to python. Also, the graph is not in that format, but I tweaked your code a bit to loop through my graph and add the info to a list then json.dump that list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're looping, but you can simply just encode the graph object.

```
import json
graph = { "random": [ { "attr1": "X", "attr2": "Y"}, {"attr1": "Z", "attr2": "V"}]}
output = json.JSONEncoder().encode(graph)
print output
# yields '{"random": [{"attr2": "Y", "attr1": "X"}, {"attr2": "V", "attr1": "Z"}]}'
```